# how to install mediapipe in phython 3.10.0? I cant install it

Tags: python, mediapipe

Latest version problem in installing the media pipe in python.
The mediapipe is not installed in python version 3.10.0. I tried but it cannot work.

.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "I can't install it" mean? What do you mean by "problem in installing"? Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Mediapipe doesn't support Python 3.10. Check its [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/) page here. It is tagged as Python 3.7, 3.8 and 3.9 but not as 3.10